# Is it possible to find the unitary matrix in the following case?

Tags: matrices, vectors, vector-analysis

I have a unitary matrix $\mathbb{U}$ given as follows $$\mathbb{U}=[\mathbb{a}~\mathbb{b}_1~\mathbb{b}_2~\cdots\mathbb{b}_{N-1}]$$ where $\mathbb{a,~b_1~\cdots b}_{N-1}$ are the complex column vectors with $N$ elements each. I only know the elements of $\mathbb{a}$ so is it possible to construct $\mathbb{U}$ with only $\mathbb{a}$ known. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely there are infinitely many: you can choose the $\{b_n\}$ to be any orthonormal set of vectors that are orthogonal to $a$ ? Or is there some further restriction?

Comment: @DaftWullie suppose $\mathbb{a}=[5~1]^T$ then according to you $\mathbb{b}=[-5~1]^T$ should suffice for the case of $L=2$. But then we have $$\mathbb{UU^H}$$ which is not an identity matrix. Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: (1) The vectors must be normalised, so $a=[5\ 1]^T/\sqrt{26}$.; (2) The stated $b$ is not orthogonal to $a$. I think you wanted $b=[1\ -5]^T/\sqrt{26}$.

Comment: yes you are right. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Now I am trying to find the $\mathbb{U}$ with $\mathbb{a}=[1 ~9~ 2]^T$ but my calculations are coming up wrong. Can you please construct $\mathbb{U}$ with $\mathbb{a}=[1~ 9 ~2]^T$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about $b_1 = [-9, 1, 0]^T$, $b_2 = [-1, -9, 41]^T$? If you need them normalized then of course $a =  [1, 9, 2]/\sqrt{86}$, $b_1 = [-9, 1, 0]^T/\sqrt{82}$, $b_2 = [-1, -9, 41]^T/\sqrt{1763}$.

Comment: Thank you florian for your answer. That works perfectly

Comment: @Florian I am using $b_1=[-9 ~1~0]^T/\sqrt{82}$ and $b_2=[-2~0~1]^T/\sqrt{5}$ but it is not working. What could be the problem. I am not getting $\mathbb{U^HU}=I$ identity matrix.

Comment: @Florian does it mean that not all the possible orthonormal vectors to $\mathbb{a}$ can be used to construct $\mathbb{U}$?

Comment: @Florian I think in my case $b_1$ and $b_2$ are not orthogonal to each other which is causing the trouble.

Comment: Yes. You want the whole matrix to be orthogonal. For this you need not only $b_1$ orthogonal to $a$ and $b_2$ orthogonal to $a$ but also $b_1$ orthogonal to $b_2$. Which it is not in your example.